# Getting the names of all files in a directory with PHP

Tags: php, file, directory, filenames

For some reason, I keep getting a '1' for the file names with this code:

```
if (is_dir($log_directory))
{
    if ($handle = opendir($log_directory))
    {
        while($file = readdir($handle) !== FALSE)
        {
            $results_array[] = $file;
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
```

When I echo each element in $results_array, I get a bunch of '1's, not the name of the file.  How do I get the name of the files?

Comment: There's a few options using [glob](http://us2.php.net/glob).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the hierarchy of a directory with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660644/get-the-hierarchy-of-a-directory-with-php)

Comment: The problem the poster had was that assignment has a very low priority, so the '!==' operator gets evaluated first and the binary result of that operation then gets assigned to $file. The only fix needed is to use ($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE"

Comment: this works: https://halgatewood.com/free-php-list-files-in-a-directory-script

Comment: from 69 votes to 70. I feel like the opposite of Hank Moody

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Don't bother with open/readdir and use [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead:

```
foreach(glob($log_directory.'/*.*') as $file) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to wrap an `array_filter(..., 'is_file')` around that glob since the question asks for files.

Comment: Not all filenames have the form `*.*`: just use `*` instead.

Comment: How can we get all files within list of extensions? E.g. if we want all .php and .js files ?

Comment: Yeah, this answer isn't very robust. Files don't need to have extensions and directories can be named `something.something`. It's better to use `array_filter` and `glob($log_directory.'/*')`.

Comment: I upvoted this becuase I just needed the simple answer and all the relevant files for my use case would be `*.*`. A more robust expression would make this an even better answer.

Comment: PHP 7.1 supports UTF-8 filenames on Windows ✌

Comment: Actually answer with DirectoryIterator is much cleaner and offers much more extension opportunities in case you need more information.

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen, how does `glob` compare with `DirectoryIterator` as an alternative? In reading through other posts, it seems it more efficient when listing a large number of files compared to `glob`.

Comment: @BartoszKubicki, when you say extension opportunities, do you mean the ability to extend the code? If yes, how is `glob` restrictive?

Answer (score 60):

[SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) style:

```php
foreach (new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__) as $file) {
  if ($file->isFile()) {
      print $file->getFilename() . "\n";
  }
}
```

Check [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) and [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) classes for the list of available methods that you can use.

Comment: Great way to get just files and just their names instead of the entire path, thanks!

Comment: Yes. For full paths, you can use `getPathname`: http://php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.getpathname.php

Answer (score 26):

As the accepted answer has two important shortfalls, I'm posting the improved answer for those new comers who are looking for a correct answer:

```
foreach (array_filter(glob('/Path/To/*'), 'is_file') as $file)
{
    // Do something with $file
}
```

1. Filtering the `glob` function results with `is_file` is necessary, because it might return some directories as well.
2. Not all files have a `.` in their names, so `*/*` pattern sucks in general.

Comment: This is a clean execution that worked for me. Previous answers showed directories in results which I did not want.

Comment: You sir need more upvotes! Actually (on windows) I had to use `basename($file)` to get only the file name instead of the whole path with filename.

Comment: The OP didn't mention he wasn't interested in "directories", besides, directories are files as well. If you also want files in sub folders, you have to use ```is_dir``` and just create a function that calls itself.

Answer (score 19):

You need to surround `$file = readdir($handle)` with parentheses.

Here you go:

```
$log_directory = 'your_dir_name_here';

$results_array = array();

if (is_dir($log_directory))
{
        if ($handle = opendir($log_directory))
        {
                //Notice the parentheses I added:
                while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE)
                {
                        $results_array[] = $file;
                }
                closedir($handle);
        }
}

//Output findings
foreach($results_array as $value)
{
    echo $value . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Just use `glob('*')`. Here's [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Answer (score 14):

I have smaller code todo this:

```
$path = "Pending2Post/";
$files = scandir($path);
foreach ($files as &$value) {
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/".$value."' target='_blank' >".$value."</a><br/><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Returning me all files but two garbage files named "." and "..". I don't have any file named "." and ".." in my directory.

Comment: Use $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..')); to free above errors I discussed.

Comment: Nice. how do I remove the extensions for the files? (I need to remove `.php` on each file.)

Comment: This is the most eloquent solution, at least for the usage I wanted.

Answer (score 9):

On some OS you get `.` `..` and `.DS_Store`, Well we can't use them so let's us hide them.

First start get all information about the files, using `scandir()`

```
// Folder where you want to get all files names from
$dir = "uploads/";

/* Hide this */
$hideName = array('.','..','.DS_Store');    

// Sort in ascending order - this is default
$files = scandir($dir);
/* While this to there no more files are */
foreach($files as $filename) {
    if(!in_array($filename, $hideName)){
       /* echo the name of the files */
       echo "$filename<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's due to operator precidence.  Try changing it to:

```
while(($file = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE)
{
    $results_array[] = $file;
}
closedir($handle);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and [`FilesystemIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php) examples:

```
/* 
 * glob() examples
 */

// get the array of full paths
$result = glob( 'path/*' );

// get the array of file names
$result = array_map( function( $item ) {
    return basename( $item );
}, glob( 'path/*' ) );


/* 
 * FilesystemIterator examples
 */

// get the array of file names by using FilesystemIterator and array_map()
$result = array_map( function( $item ) {
    // $item: SplFileInfo object
    return $item->getFilename();
}, iterator_to_array( new FilesystemIterator( 'path' ), false ) );

// get the array of file names by using FilesystemIterator and iterator_apply() filter
$it = new FilesystemIterator( 'path' );
iterator_apply( 
    $it, 
    function( $item, &$result ) {
        // $item: FilesystemIterator object that points to current element
        $result[] = (string) $item;
        // The function must return TRUE in order to continue iterating
        return true;
    }, 
    array( $it, &$result )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just try the `scandir(Path)` function. it is fast and easy to implement

Syntax:

```
$files = scandir("somePath");
```

This Function returns a list of file into an Array.

to view the result, you can try

```
var_dump($files);
```

Or

```
foreach($files as $file)
{ 
echo $file."< br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to list directories and files would be using the `RecursiveTreeIterator` answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37548504/2032235.

A thorough explanation of `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and iterators in PHP can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12236744/2032235

Answer (score 0):

I just use this code:

```
<?php
    $directory = "Images";
    echo "<div id='images'><p>$directory ...<p>";
    $Files = glob("Images/S*.jpg");
    foreach ($Files as $file) {
        echo "$file<br>";
    }
    echo "</div>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if ($handle = opendir("C:\wamp\www\yoursite/download/")) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "<b>" . preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $entry) . "</b>";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Source: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-fetch-all-files-name-from-folder.html

Answer (score 0):

Recursive code to explore all the file contained in a directory ('$path' contains the path of the directory):

```
function explore_directory($path)
{
    $scans = scandir($path);

    foreach($scans as $scan)
    {
        $new_path = $path.$scan;

        if(is_dir($new_path))
        {
            $new_path = $new_path."/";
            explore_directory($new_path);
        }
        else // A file
        {
            /*
                  Body of code
            */
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Little something I created for this:

```
function getFiles($path) {
    if (is_dir($path)) {
        $res = array();
        foreach (array_filter(glob($path ."*"), 'is_file') as $file) {
            array_push($res, str_replace($path, "", $file));                
        }
        return $res;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will list the files and create links that open in a new window. Just like a regular server index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index of Files</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Index of Files</h1>
    <ul>
        <?php
        // Get the current directory
        $dir = '.';
        
        // Open a directory handle
        if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
            // Loop through each file in the directory
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                // Exclude directories and the current/parent directory entries
                if ($file != "." && $file != ".." && !is_dir($file)) {
                    // Generate the link to the file
                    $link = $dir . '/' . $file;
                    
                    // Output the link
                    echo '<li><a href="' . $link . '" target="_blank">' . $file . '</a></li>';
                }
            }
            
            // Close the directory handle
            closedir($handle);
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```