# How does RecursiveIteratorIterator work in PHP?

Tags: php, iterator, spl

How does `RecursiveIteratorIterator` work?

The PHP manual has nothing much documented or explained. What is the difference between `IteratorIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator`?

Comment: there is an example at http://php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php and there is also an Introduction at http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoriterator.php - can you please point out what exactly you have trouble understanding. What should the Manual contain in order to make it easier to grasp?

Comment: If you ask how `RecursiveIteratorIterator` works, have you understood already how `IteratorIterator` works? I mean it is basically the same, only the interface that is consumed by the two is different. And are you more interested in some examples or do you want to see the diff of the underlying C code implementation?

Comment: @Gordon i was not sure how does single foreach loop can traverse all elements in tree structure

Comment: @hakra i am now trying to study all built in interfaces as well as spl interface and iterator implementetion.I was interested to know how does it works in background with forach loop with some examples.

Comment: @hakre They are both actualy very different. `IteratorIterator` maps `Iterator`and `IteratorAggregate` into an `Iterator`, where `REcusiveIteratorIterator` is used to traverse recusivly a `RecursiveIterator`

Answer (score 279, accepted):

[`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/class.recursiveiteratoriterator) is a concrete [`Iterator`](http://php.net/class.iterator) implementing [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). It enables a programmer to traverse a container object that implements the `RecursiveIterator` interface, see [Iterator in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator) for the general principles, types, semantics and patterns of iterators.

In difference to [`IteratorIterator`](http://php.net/class.iteratoriterator) which is a concrete `Iterator` implementing object traversal in linear order (and by default accepting any kind of [`Traversable`](http://php.net/class.Traversable) in its constructor), the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` allows looping over all nodes in an *ordered tree* of objects and its constructor takes a `RecursiveIterator`.

In short: `RecursiveIteratorIterator` allows you to loop over a tree, `IteratorIterator` allows you to loop over a list. I show that with some code examples below soon.

Technically this works by breaking out of linearity by traversing all of a nodes' children (if any). This is possible because by definition all children of a node are again a `RecursiveIterator`. The toplevel `Iterator` then internally stacks the different `RecursiveIterator`s by their depth and keeps a pointer to the current active sub `Iterator` for traversal.

This allows to visit all nodes of a tree.

The underlying principles are the same as with `IteratorIterator`: An interface specifies the type of iteration and the base iterator class is the implementation of these semantics. Compare with the examples below, for linear looping  with `foreach` you normally do not think about the implementation details much unless you need to define a new `Iterator` (e.g. when some concrete type itself does not implement `Traversable`).

For recursive traversal - unless you do not use a pre-defined `Traversal` that already has recursive traversal iteration - you normally *need* to instantiate the existing `RecursiveIteratorIterator` iteration or even write a recursive traversal iteration that is a `Traversable` your own to have this type of traversal iteration with `foreach`.

> *Tip:* You probably didn't implement the one nor the other your own, so this might be something worth to do for your practical experience of the differences they have. You find a DIY suggestion at the end of the answer.

Technical differences in short:

- While `IteratorIterator` takes any `Traversable` for linear traversal, `RecursiveIteratorIterator` needs a more specific `RecursiveIterator` to loop over a tree.
- Where `IteratorIterator` exposes its main `Iterator` via `getInnerIerator()`, `RecursiveIteratorIterator` provides the current active sub-`Iterator` only via that method.
- While `IteratorIterator` is totally not aware of anything like parent or children, `RecursiveIteratorIterator` knows how to get and traverse children as well.
- `IteratorIterator` does not need a stack of iterators, `RecursiveIteratorIterator` has such a stack and knows the active sub-iterator.
- Where `IteratorIterator` has its order due to linearity and no choice, `RecursiveIteratorIterator` has a choice for further traversal and needs to decide per each node (decided via [mode per `RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php)).
- `RecursiveIteratorIterator` has more methods than `IteratorIterator`.

To summarize: `RecursiveIterator` is a concrete type of iteration (looping over a tree) that works on its own iterators, namely `RecursiveIterator`. That is the same underlying principle as with `IteratorIerator`, but the type of iteration is different (linear order).

Ideally you can create your own set, too. The only thing necessary is that your iterator implements `Traversable` which is possible via `Iterator` or `IteratorAggregate`. Then you can use it with `foreach`. For example some kind of ternary tree traversal recursive  iteration object together with the according iteration interface for the container object(s).

---

Let's review with some real-life examples that are not that abstract. Between interfaces, concrete iterators, container objects and iteration semantics this maybe is not a that bad idea.

Take a directory listing as an example. Consider you have got the following file and directory tree on disk:

> [image: Directory Tree]

While a iterator with linear order just traverse over the toplevel folder and files (a single directory listing), the recursive iterator traverses through subfolders as well and list all folders and files (a directory listing with listings of its subdirectories):

```
Non-Recursive        Recursive
=============        =========

   [tree]            [tree]
    ├ dirA            ├ dirA
    └ fileA           │ ├ dirB
                      │ │ └ fileD
                      │ ├ fileB
                      │ └ fileC
                      └ fileA
```

You can easily compare this with `IteratorIterator` which does no recursion for traversing the directory tree. And the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` which can traverse into the tree as the Recursive listing shows.

At first a very basic example with a [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/class.directoryiterator) that implements [`Traversable`](http://php.net/Traversable) which allows [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) to *iterate* over it:

```
$path = 'tree';
$dir  = new DirectoryIterator($path);

echo "[$path]\n";
foreach ($dir as $file) {
    echo " ├ $file\n";
}
```

The exemplary output for the directory structure above then is:

```
[tree]
 ├ .
 ├ ..
 ├ dirA
 ├ fileA
```

As you see this is not yet using `IteratorIterator` or `RecursiveIteratorIterator`. Instead it just just using `foreach` that operates on the `Traversable` interface.

As `foreach` by default only knows the type of iteration named linear order, we might want to specify the type of iteration explicitly. At first glance it might seem too verbose, but for demonstration purposes (and to make the difference with `RecursiveIteratorIterator` more visible later), lets specify the linear type of iteration explicitly specifying the `IteratorIterator` type of iteration for the directory listing:

```
$files = new IteratorIterator($dir);

echo "[$path]\n";
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo " ├ $file\n";
}
```

This example is *nearly* identical with the first one, the difference is that `$files` is now an `IteratorIterator` type of iteration for `Traversable` `$dir`:

```
$files = new IteratorIterator($dir);
```

As usual the act of iteration is performed by the `foreach`:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
```

The output is *exactly* the same. So what is different? Different is the object used within the `foreach`. In the first example it is a `DirectoryIterator` in the second example it is the `IteratorIterator`. This shows the flexibility iterators have: You can replace them with each other, the code inside `foreach` just continue to work as expected.

Lets start to get the whole listing, including subdirectories.

As we now have specified the type of iteration, let's consider to change it to another type of iteration.

We know we need to traverse the whole tree now, not only the first level. To have that work with a simple `foreach` we need a different type of iterator: [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveIteratorIterator). And that one can only iterate over container objects that have the [`RecursiveIterator` interface](http://php.net/RecursiveIterator).

The interface is a contract. Any class implementing it can be used together with the `RecursiveIteratorIterator`. An example of such a class is the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveDirectoryIterator), which is something like the recursive variant of `DirectoryIterator`.

Lets see a first code example before writing any other sentence with the I-word:

```
$dir  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);

echo "[$path]\n";
foreach ($dir as $file) {
    echo " ├ $file\n";
}
```

This third example is *nearly* identical with the first one, however it creates some different output:

```
[tree]
 ├ tree\.
 ├ tree\..
 ├ tree\dirA
 ├ tree\fileA
```

Okay, not that different, the filename now contains the pathname in front, but the rest looks similar as well.

As the example shows, even the directory object already imlements the `RecursiveIterator` interface, this is not yet enough to make `foreach` traverse the whole directory tree. This is where the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` comes into action. *Example 4* shows how:

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);

echo "[$path]\n";
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo " ├ $file\n";
}
```

Using the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` instead of just the previous `$dir` object will make `foreach` to traverse over all files and directories in a recursive manner. This then lists all files, as the type of object iteration has been specified now:

```
[tree]
 ├ tree\.
 ├ tree\..
 ├ tree\dirA\.
 ├ tree\dirA\..
 ├ tree\dirA\dirB\.
 ├ tree\dirA\dirB\..
 ├ tree\dirA\dirB\fileD
 ├ tree\dirA\fileB
 ├ tree\dirA\fileC
 ├ tree\fileA
```

This should already demonstrate the difference between flat and tree traversal. The `RecursiveIteratorIterator` is able to traverse any tree-like structure as a list of elements. Because there is more information (like the level the iteration takes currently place), it is possible to access the iterator object while iterating over it and for example indent the output:

```
echo "[$path]\n";
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $indent = str_repeat('   ', $files->getDepth());
    echo $indent, " ├ $file\n";
}
```

And output of *Example 5*:

```
[tree]
 ├ tree\.
 ├ tree\..
    ├ tree\dirA\.
    ├ tree\dirA\..
       ├ tree\dirA\dirB\.
       ├ tree\dirA\dirB\..
       ├ tree\dirA\dirB\fileD
    ├ tree\dirA\fileB
    ├ tree\dirA\fileC
 ├ tree\fileA
```

Sure this does not win a beauty contest, but it shows that with the recursive iterator there is more information available than just the linear order of *key* and *value*. Even `foreach` can only express this kind of linearity, accessing the iterator itself allows to obtain more information.

Similar to the meta-information there are also different ways possible how to traverse the tree and therefore order the output. This is the [*Mode* of the `RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.construct.php) and it can be set with the constructor.

The next example will tell the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to remove the dot entries (`.` and `..`) as we do not need them. But also the recursion mode will be changed to take the parent element (the subdirectory) first (`SELF_FIRST`) before the children (the files and sub-subdirs in the subdirectory):

```
$dir  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

echo "[$path]\n";
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $indent = str_repeat('   ', $files->getDepth());
    echo $indent, " ├ $file\n";
}
```

The output now shows the subdirectory entries properly listed, if you compare with the previous output those were not there:

```
[tree]
 ├ tree\dirA
    ├ tree\dirA\dirB
       ├ tree\dirA\dirB\fileD
    ├ tree\dirA\fileB
    ├ tree\dirA\fileC
 ├ tree\fileA
```

The recursion mode therefore controls what and when a brach or leaf in the tree is returned, for the directory example:

- `LEAVES_ONLY` (default): Only list files, no directories.
- `SELF_FIRST` (above): List directory and then the files in there.
- `CHILD_FIRST` (w/o example): List files in subdirectory first, then the directory.

Output of *Example 5* with the two other modes:

```
  LEAVES_ONLY                           CHILD_FIRST

  [tree]                                [tree]
         ├ tree\dirA\dirB\fileD                ├ tree\dirA\dirB\fileD
      ├ tree\dirA\fileB                     ├ tree\dirA\dirB
      ├ tree\dirA\fileC                     ├ tree\dirA\fileB
   ├ tree\fileA                             ├ tree\dirA\fileC
                                        ├ tree\dirA
                                        ├ tree\fileA
```

When you compare that with standard traversal, all these things are not available. Recursive iteration therefore is a little bit more complex when you need to wrap your head around it, however it is easy to use because it behaves just like an iterator, you put it into a `foreach` and done.

I think these are enough examples for one answer. You can find the full source-code as well as an example to display nice-looking ascii-trees in this gist: https://gist.github.com/3599532

> ***Do It Yourself:* Make the `RecursiveTreeIterator` Work Line by Line.**

*Example 5* demonstrated that there is meta-information about the iterator's state available. However, this was purposefully demonstrated *within* the `foreach` iteration. In real life this naturally belongs inside the `RecursiveIterator`.

A better example is the [`RecursiveTreeIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveTreeIterator), it takes care of indenting, prefixing and so on. See the following code fragment:

```
$dir   = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$lines = new RecursiveTreeIterator($dir);
$unicodeTreePrefix($lines);
echo "[$path]\n", implode("\n", iterator_to_array($lines));
```

The `RecursiveTreeIterator` is intended to work line by line, the output is pretty straight forward with one little problem:

```
[tree]
 ├ tree\dirA
 │ ├ tree\dirA\dirB
 │ │ └ tree\dirA\dirB\fileD
 │ ├ tree\dirA\fileB
 │ └ tree\dirA\fileC
 └ tree\fileA
```

When used in combination with a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` it displays the whole pathname and not just the filename. The rest looks good. This is because the file-names are generated by `SplFileInfo`. Those should be displayed as the basename instead. The desired output is the following:

```
/// Solved ///

[tree]
 ├ dirA
 │ ├ dirB
 │ │ └ fileD
 │ ├ fileB
 │ └ fileC
 └ fileA
```

Create a decorator class that can be used with `RecursiveTreeIterator` instead of the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`. It should provide the basename of the current `SplFileInfo` instead of the pathname. The final code fragment could then look like:

```
$lines = new RecursiveTreeIterator(
    new DiyRecursiveDecorator($dir)
);
$unicodeTreePrefix($lines);
echo "[$path]\n", implode("\n", iterator_to_array($lines));
```

These fragments including `$unicodeTreePrefix` are part of the gist in *Appendix: Do It Yourself: Make the `RecursiveTreeIterator` Work Line by Line.*.

Comment: It doesn't answer the questions posed, contains factual errors and misses core points when you move on to customising the iteration. All in all, it looks like a poor attempt to get the bounty on a topic that you don't know much about or, if you do, cannot distill into an answer to the questions posed.

Comment: Well which does not answer my "why" question, you just make more words without saying much. Maybe you start with actually an Error that counts? Point to it, don't keep it your secret.

Comment: The very first sentence is incorrect: "RecursiveIteratorIterator is an IteratorIterator that supports…", this is not true.

Comment: You also forget to mention the **entire purpose** of the `IteratorIterator`, its reason for being.

Comment: And you forget to mention **how `RecursiveIteratorIterator` works** (it knows how to call `getChildren()`, for example).

Comment: Your entire answer is showing examples of "standard" traversal, versus "recursive" traversal, nothing more.

Comment: You forget to mention, when talking about `SELF_FIRST`, the other modes available and especially the name of the default mode (re. "core points" mentioned earlier).

Comment: @salathe: Tank you for your feedback. I edited the answer to adress it. The first sentence indeed was wrong and incomplete. I have still left out the concrete implementation details of `RecursiveIteratorIterator` because this is in common with other types but I did give some technical infos  of how it actually works. The examples I think show well the differences: the type of iteration *is* the main difference between the two. No idea if you buy the type of iteration you coin it a little differently but IMHO not easy with the semantics types of iteration have.

Comment: The first part is improved somewhat, but once you start moving onto the examples it still veers into factual inaccuracies. If you cropped the answer at the horizontal rule, it would be much improved.

Comment: @salathe: yes it's not perfectly formulated but I didn't want to drop the examples.

Answer (score 34):

> What is the difference of `IteratorIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator`?

To understand the difference between these two iterators, one must first understand a little bit about the naming conventions used and what we mean by "recursive" iterators.

#### Recursive and non-recursive iterators

PHP has non-"recursive" iterators, such as `ArrayIterator` and `FilesystemIterator`. There are also "recursive" iterators such as the `RecursiveArrayIterator` and `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`. The latter have methods enabling them to be drilled down into, the former do not.

When instances of these iterators are looped over on their own, even the recursive ones, the values only come from the "top" level even if looping over a nested array or directory with sub-directories.

The recursive iterators *implement* recursive behaviour (via `hasChildren()`, `getChildren()`) but do not *exploit* it.

It might be better to think of the recursive iterators as "recursible" iterators, they have the *ability* to be iterated recursively but simply iterating over an instance of one of these classes will not do that.  To exploit the recursive behaviour, keep reading.

#### RecursiveIteratorIterator

This is where the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` comes in to play.  It has the knowledge of how to call the "recursible" iterators in such a way as to drill down into the structure in a normal, flat, loop. It puts the recursive behaviour into action. It essentially does the work of stepping over each of the values in the iterator, looking to see if there are "children" to recurse into or not, and stepping into and out of those collections of children. You stick an instance of `RecursiveIteratorIterator` into a foreach, and *it* dives into the structure so that you don't have to.

If the `RecursiveIteratorIterator` was not used, you would have to write your own recursive loops to exploit the recursive behaviour, checking against the "recursible" iterator's `hasChildren()` and using `getChildren()`.

So that's a *brief* overview of `RecursiveIteratorIterator`, how is it different from `IteratorIterator`?  Well, you're basically asking the same sort of question as *What is the difference between a kitten and a tree?* Just because both appear in the same encyclopaedia (or manual, for the iterators) doesn't mean you should get confused between the two.

#### IteratorIterator

The job of the `IteratorIterator` is to take any `Traversable` object, and wrap it such that it satisfies the `Iterator` interface. A use for this is to then be able to apply iterator-specific behaviour on the non-iterator object.

To give a practical example, the `DatePeriod` class is `Traversable` but not an `Iterator`. As such, we can loop over its values with `foreach()` but cannot do other things that we ordinarily would with an iterator, such as filtering.

**TASK**: Loop over the Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays of the next four weeks.

<sup>Yes, this is trivial by `foreach`-ing over the `DatePeriod` and using an `if()` within the loop; but that's not the point of this example!</sup>

```
$period = new DatePeriod(new DateTime, new DateInterval('P1D'), 28);
$dates  = new CallbackFilterIterator($period, function ($date) {
    return in_array($date->format('l'), array('Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Friday'));
});
foreach ($dates as $date) { … }
```

The above snippet won't work because the `CallbackFilterIterator` expects an instance of a class that implements the `Iterator` interface, which `DatePeriod` does not. However, since it is `Traversable` we can easily satisfy that requirement by using `IteratorIterator`.

```
$period = new IteratorIterator(new DatePeriod(…));
```

As you can see, this has *nothing* whatsoever to do with iterating over iterator classes nor recursion, and therein lies the difference between `IteratorIterator` and `RecursiveIteratorIterator`.

#### Summary

`RecursiveIteraratorIterator` is for iterating over a `RecursiveIterator` ("recursible" iterator), exploiting the recursive behaviour that is available.

`IteratorIterator` is for applying `Iterator` behaviour to non-iterator, `Traversable` objects.

Comment: Isn't `IteratorIterator` just the standard type of linear order traversal for `Traversable` objects? Those which could be used without it just in `foreach` as is? And even further, isn't a `RecursiveIterator` *always* a `Traversable` and therefore not only `IteratorIterator` but also `RecursiveIteratorIterator` always *"for applying `Iterator` behaviour to non-iterator, Traversable objects"*? (I'd now say `foreach` applies the type of iteration via the iterator object on container objects that implement an iterator-type  interface so these are iterator-container-objects, always `Traversable`)

Comment: As my answer states, `IteratorIterator` is a class that is all about wrapping `Traversable` objects in an `Iterator`. *Nothing more*. You seem to be applying the term more generally.

Comment: Seemingly informative answer. One question, wouldn't RecursiveIteratorIterator also wrap objects so that they would also have access to Iterator behavior? The only difference between the two would be that the RecursiveIteratorIterator can drill down, whereas the IteratorIterator cannot?

Comment: @salathe, do you know why recursive iterator (RecursiveDirectoryIterator) does not implements hasChildren(), getChildren() behaviour?

Comment: @anru, what makes you think it doesn't implement those methods? It does.

Comment: +1 for saying "recursible". The name lead me astray for a long time  because the `Recursive` in `RecursiveIterator` implies behavior, whereas a more suitable name would have been one which describes capability, like `RecursibleIterator`.

Comment: It looks to me like RecursiveIterators always needs to be wrapped by `RecursiveIteratorIterator`.  If thats the case, then I think it would be an improvement for the PHP language to get rid of the public `RecursiveIteratorIterator` class and instead `new RecursiveArrayIterator` should return an iterator that can be directly used in a foreach loop and iterates recursively.  Or is there any use-case where you want to use a RecursiveIterators without `RecursiveIteratorIterator`?

Comment: @Adam: We can't get rid of the public `RecursiveIteratorIterator` class as it is the de-facto implementation of the recursive traversal that can be contracted with the `RecursiveIterator` interface. Perhaps a "you can't have the cookie and it eat, too" situation. What you question however, has a basis I'd say. My suggestion: When you already know that your type has (only this kind of) traversal, make it an iterator aggregate ([`implements IteratorAggregate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoraggregate.php)) and give that iterator directly from the `getIterator()` method.

Answer (score 0):

When used with `iterator_to_array()`, `RecursiveIteratorIterator` will recursively walk the array to find all the values. Meaning that it will flatten the original array.

`IteratorIterator` will keep the original hierarchical structure.

This example will show you clearly the difference:

```
$array = array(
               'ford',
               'model' => 'F150',
               'color' => 'blue', 
               'options' => array('radio' => 'satellite')
               );

$recursiveIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));
var_dump(iterator_to_array($recursiveIterator, true));

$iterator = new IteratorIterator(new ArrayIterator($array));
var_dump(iterator_to_array($iterator,true));
```

Comment: This is totally misleading. `new IteratorIterator(new ArrayIterator($array))` is equivalent to `new ArrayIterator($array)`, that is, the outer `IteratorIterator` is doing nothing. Moreover, the flattening of the output has nothing to do with `iterator_to_array` – it merely converts the iterator to an array. The flattening is a property of the way `RecursiveArrayIterator` walks its inner iterator.

Answer (score 0):

RecursiveDirectoryIterator it displays the whole pathname and not just the filename. The rest looks good. This is because the file-names are generated by SplFileInfo. Those should be displayed as the basename instead. The desired output is the following:

```
$path =__DIR__;
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir,RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
while ($files->valid()) {
    $file = $files->current();
    $filename = $file->getFilename();
    $deep = $files->getDepth();
    $indent = str_repeat('│ ', $deep);
    $files->next();
    $valid = $files->valid();
    if ($valid and ($files->getDepth() - 1 == $deep or $files->getDepth() == $deep)) {
        echo $indent, "├ $filename\n";
    } else {
        echo $indent, "└ $filename\n";
    }
}
```

output:

```
tree
 ├ dirA
 │ ├ dirB
 │ │ └ fileD
 │ ├ fileB
 │ └ fileC
 └ fileA
```