# RecursiveFilterIterator re-instantiated within RecursiveIteratorIterator?

Tags: php, spl

The standard way to recursively scan directories via SPL iterators is:

```
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    print $file->getPathname() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I want a composable set of filters to apply to my recursive file search. I'm using a `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to scan a directory structure.

I want to apply more than one filter to my directory structure.

My set up code:

```
$filters = new FilterRuleset(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)
);
$filters->addFilter(new FilterLapsedDirs);
$filters->addFilter(new IncludeExtension('wav'));
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    $filters, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);
```

I thought I could apply N filters by using rule set:

```
class FilterRuleset extends RecursiveFilterIterator {
    private $filters = array();

    public function addFilter($filter) {
        $this->filters[] = $filter;
    }

    public function accept() {
        $file = $this->current();

        foreach ($this->filters as $filter) {
            if (!$filter->accept($file)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The filtering I set up is not working as intended. When I check the filters in `FilterRuleset` they are populated on the first call, then blank on subsequent calls. Its as if internally `RecursiveIteratorIterator` is re-instantiating my `FilterRuleset`.

```
    public function accept() {
        print_r($this->filters);
        $file = $this->current();

        foreach ($this->filters as $filter) {
            if (!$filter->accept($file)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => FilterLapsedDirs Object
        (
        )

    [1] => IncludeExtension Object
        (
            [ext:private] => wav
        )
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

I'm using PHP 5.1.6 but have tested it on 5.4.14 and there's no difference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When I check the filters in FilterRuleset they are populated on the first call, then blank on subsequent calls. Its as if internally RecursiveIteratorIterator is re-instantiating my FilterRuleset.

Yes, this is exactly the case. Each time you go into a subdirectory the array is empty because per recursive iterator rules, the recursive filter iterator needs to provide the child iterators.

So you've got two options here:

1. Apply filters on the flattened iteration, that is *after* tree-traversal. It looks feasible in your case as long as you only need to filter each individual file - not children.
2. The standard way: Take care that `getChildren()` returns  a configured `FilterRuleset` recursive-filter-iterator object with the filters set.

I start with the second one because it's quickly done and the normal way to do this.

You overwrite the `getChildren()` parent method by adding it to your class. Then you take the result of the parent (which is the new `FilterRuleset` for the children and set the private member. This is possible in PHP (in case you wonder that his works because it's a private member) because it's on the same level of the class hierarchy. You then just return it and done:

```
class FilterRuleset extends RecursiveFilterIterator
{
    private $filters = array();

    ...

    public function getChildren() {
        $children = parent::getChildren();
        $children->filters = $this->filters;
        return $children;
    }
}
```

The other (first) variant is that you basically "degrade" it to the "flat" filter, that is a standard `FilterIterator`. Therefore you first do the recursive iteration with a `RecursiveIteratorIterator` and then you wrap that into your filter-iterator. As the tree has been already traversed by the earlier iterator, all this recursive stuff is not needed any longer.

So first of all turn it into a the `FilterIterator`:

```
class FilterRuleset extends FilterIterator
{
   ...
}
```

The only change is from what you extend with that class. And the you instantiate in a slightly different order:

```
$path  = __DIR__;
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);

$filtered = new FilterRuleset($files);
$filtered->addFilter(Accept::byCallback(function () {
    return true;
}));

foreach ($filtered as $file) {
    echo $file->getPathname(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

I hope these examples are clear. If you play around with these and you run into a problem (or even if not), feedback always welcome.

Ah and before I forget it: Here is the mock I've used to create filters in my example above:

```
class Accept
{
    private $callback;

    public function __construct($callback) {
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    public function accept($subject) {
        return call_user_func($this->callback, $subject);
    }

    public static function byCallback($callback) {
        return new self($callback);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I'll get it working first then accept the answer.

Comment: Also, if you go to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077177/how-does-recursiveiteratoriterator-work-in-php/12236744#12236744
@hakre explains again the concept of IteratorIterator vs RecursiveIteratorIterator