# listing all jpg files in all sub folders, then display those that contains terms from input field

Tags: php, forms, variables, preg-match, input-field

I was actually able to find a post by another user here which lead me in the right direction. I haven't bookmarked it but i will as soon as i have a bit of time. Meanwhile, here is the solution to my problem:

```
<form name="search-form" onclick="this.form.submit()" id="search-form" method="post">
<input size="30" name="search" type="text" id="search" />
<input class="button" type="submit" name="stylesearch" value="search" />
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['stylesearch']))
    {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    if (@get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
        $search = stripslashes($search);
        }
    $it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("galleries");
    $allowed=array("jpg");
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {
        if (false !== stripos($file, $search))
    {
    echo 'You have searched for the following '.$it.' style(s): <a href="'. $file . '" target="">'.str_replace(array(' - ','.jpg'), array(' '), $search).'</a>' . "<br>";
        }
    }
echo " ";
}
else
{
echo "<p>search a style</p>";
}
?>
```

> Here is the problem:
>
> I have a "gallery/" folder which contains multiple sub-folders that go
>   a few levels deep. I have successfully made inventory of all jpgs
>   contained in all subfolders, in a nice list with direct links to the
>   pictures. That's the easy part.
>
> What i'd like to do is to have an input box where i can type a term,
>   and upon clicking Submit, only the files that contain that term in the
>   file name will show up in the list.
>
> I have created the input button, and when you click it it shows the
>   entire list (meaning it simply runs the code as it is supposed to
>   run). For the life of me, i can't understand how to make it work in a
>   way that it will show only the files matching what i type in the
>   $search field.
>
> Is what i am trying to do even possible?
>
> Here is the code:
>
> ```
> <form action="searchlist.php" method="post"><input name="searchstyle" id="searchstyle" type="search" value=""><button
> ```
>
> name="stylesearch" id="stylesearch">style search
>       '.str_replace(array(' - ','.jpg'), array(' '),
>   $file).'' . "
> ";
>                             }
>                             else{
>                             $dirs[]=$dest;
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }           }       return $files;      }   printAll(getcwd());
>       }
>       ?>

Comment: You find example code and more in related questions. For example here: [RecursiveFilterIterator re-instantiated within RecursiveIteratorIterator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16712253/367456)

Comment: Uh, I'm guessing by the question, SPL is a little difficult

Comment: Thanks, i don't really know much about regular expressions, so the related link about RecursiveIteratorIterator didn't help much at all, as what i need is a way to type a term into the search field so that only the file names that contain the terms typed will display in the list.