# PHP RecursiveDirectoryIterator Self_first isnt working

Tags: php

Im trying to traverse a file tree in a self first order, so I would expect the files in a directory to be all listed first before going down to the next level. However for some reason this is not happening. Please find below my code

```
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($f["path"],   RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($it as $fileObject) {
    echo $fileObject."\n";
}
```

And this prints the following example (if my input directory is /data/documents/

- /data/documents/file name 1.pdf
- /data/documents/filename 2.pdf
- /data/documents/dir A/file 4.jpg
- /data/documents/dir A
- /data/documents/file name 5.pdf
- /data/documents/dirB/filex.pdf
- /data/documents/dirB/filey.jpg
- /data/documents/dirB/dirC/filew.pdf
- /data/documents/dirB/dirC/filev.pdf
- /data/documents/dirB/dirC
- /data/documents/dirB
- /data/documents/file name r.pdf

Yes, the files and sometimes the directories have spaces in their naming. I'm running this on the command line, using php version 
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Dec 11 2013 03:29:57)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I would expect the following output instead;

- /data/documents/dir A
- /data/documents/dir A/file 4.jpg
- /data/documents/dirB
- /data/documents/dirB/filex.pdf
- /data/documents/dirB/filey.jpg
- /data/documents/dirB/dirC
- /data/documents/dirB/dirC/filew.pdf
- /data/documents/dirB/dirC/filev.pdf
- /data/documents/file name 1.pdf
- /data/documents/filename 2.pdf
- /data/documents/file name 5.pdf
- /data/documents/file name r.pdf

Comment: You mean, the subdirectories should be listed after the first level files?

Comment: Well, with SELF_FIRST selected as option, I think the first level files should come first, then the directories and their subdirectories. As you can tell, I got some first level files before subdirectories and some after.

Comment: From this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12236744/2706988. `::SELF_FIRST` List directory and then the files in there.

Comment: Either way, as you can tell, that order is not followed. files and directories are all mixed.

Comment: Edit your question and show us your expected results.

Comment: @RahilWazir see updated section above

Answer (score 3):

**Although a long long time ago you asked the question, Here is a solution. Also, I was looking an answer for the same problem.**

```
<?php

    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/path"),RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    $html = "";

    foreach($iterator as $folder)
    {
      if($folder->isDir())
      {
        $all_files = glob($folder->getRealpath()."/*.*");

        foreach ($all_files as $filename)
        {

          $html .= $filename."<br>";
        }
      }
    }
      echo $html;
    ?>
```