# PHP using the recursive array iterator class

Tags: php, arrays

I'm a bit confused. I have the following array: I am trying to use the STL iterator to loop through it and return sum all the values of any array where Name = Dodge. I noticed I cannot do `$cars['Price']` as I could with a for each loop. How do I get the price of the car?

```
$cars = Array {

     array[0] {
               'Name' => 'Dodge',
               'Drive' => '4W',
               'Price' => '15,000'

              },
     array[1] {
               'Name' => 'Corolla',
               'Drive' => '2W',
               'Price' => '17,300'
               }
         ..
}
```

Is this correct:

```
try {
    $iter = new RecursiveArrayIterator($cars);

    // loop through the array
    $all_totals = array();
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iter) as $key => $value) 
    {

        if($key == 'Name' && $value == 'Dodge') 
        {
            //how to get the Price of the car?

            //push into totals array:
            $all_totals[$value] = $value;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `RecursiveIterator` for this task, when it can be solved pretty straight-forward with simple `foreach` loop?

Comment: @raina77ow I know it can I was trying to learn the RecursiveIterator class. Also from what I've read the SPL is faster for large arrays

Comment: See, you won't learn how to wield a screwdriver when you only have nails to deal with. ) RecursiveIterator is most suitable when you have to process complex hierarchies - trees, in particular. Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077177/how-does-recursiveiteratoriterator-work-in-php) for a very detailed explanation of how this SPL feature can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
foreach($cars as $key=>$value){
  echo $value['Name']." has a price of ".$value['Price'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this code for perticular Dodge car price.

$sumofDodgeCar = 0;

foreach($cars as $value){
    if($value['Name']=='Dodge') {
         echo $value['Name']." has a price of ".$value['Price'];
    $sumofDodgeCar = $sumofDodgeCar + $value['Price'];
    }
}

echo "All Dodge car Price Sum :".$sumofDodgeCar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[array_keys()][1]` for this.

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
```