# Array remove parent numeric array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

how can i make **this Array:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["plz"]=>
    string(4) "4460"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["plz"]=>
    string(4) "4000"
  }
}
```

**Becomes something like this just need the values in one array keys doesnt matter:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "4460"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "4000"
}
```

is there a helper function or something which can help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If key is known beforehand:**

If you're using PHP 5.5+, you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) to extract all the sub-arrays with `plz` key:

```
$result = array_column($array, 'plz');
```

The same can be achieved using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) if you're using an older version of PHP:

```
$result = array_map(function($sub) { return $sub['plz']; }, $array);
```

---

**If key is not known beforehand:**

Use [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/array_walk_recursive):

```
$result = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v) use (&$result) { $result[] = $v; });
```

Note that it works recursively, so it'd still work if you have more complex arrays.

Alternatively, you could use [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) class:

```
$result = array();
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

foreach($iterator as $value) {
    $result[] = $value;
}
```

For more details, see this question: [How does RecursiveIteratorIterator work in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077177/how-does-recursiveiteratoriterator-work-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map('array_values', $array));
```

1. Get numerically indexed arrays from the sub-arrays using using `array_values()`
2. Merge those arrays using `array_merge()`