# Get only one type of each basename, by prioritized set of extensions

Tags: php

I have a set of files that looks like this:

```
image01.png
image01.jpg
image02.png
image02.jpg
image03.png
image03.jpg
image03.gif
```

Can anyone think of a better way to get only one file from each set with the same basename, and based on a prioritized set of extensions? All the `continue` statements in my current code looks... not so good. And I am positive I will add more filetypes to the mix, so it won't get any prettier (or easier to manage for that matter).

```
while(($Filename = readdir($DirHandle)) !== FALSE){
    $Ext = pathinfo($Filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $Basename = basename($Filename, '.'.$Ext);
    switch($Ext){
        case 'png':
            // highest priority, we're good
            break;

        case 'jpeg':
        case 'jpg':
            // is there a higher-priority filetype with the same basename?
            if(file_exists($Dir.'/'.$Basename.'.png'))
                continue 2; // then, let's proceed to the next file
            break;

        case 'gif':
            if(file_exists($Dir.'/'.$Basename.'.png'))
                continue 2;
            elseif(file_exists($Dir.'/'.$Basename.'.jpeg'))
                continue 2;
            elseif(file_exists($Dir.'/'.$Basename.'.jpg'))
                continue 2;
            break;

        // etc. etc...

        default:
            // not a filetype we're interested in at all
            continue 2;
    }
}
```

A `scandir()` solution would be fine too. But even then, I personally couldn't think of any better solution..

Answer (score 0):

You could simply make use of PHP's [SPL Extensions..](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php)

```
$it_files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("images",FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_SELF));

$images = array();
foreach ($it_files as $file) {
    if(!array_key_exists(pathinfo($file)['filename'],$images) && exif_imagetype($file))
    {
        $images[pathinfo($file)['filename']]=pathinfo($file)['basename'];
    }
}
print_r($images);
```

###Explanation :

The above code recursively checks all the files under the `images` directory. Each file is checked whether it is an image or not using `exif_imagetype` so don't have to specify the extensions like `.jpg , .jpeg, .gif`... etc.

Let us consider the same files you mentioned are there in the `images` directory.. First it will add `image01.png` to the `$images` array since it is an image and no other occurence was there. Now, the `image01.jpg` will not be added since their filenames match. Now, the `image02.png` will be added.. an so on.

Comment: Why not just use [`getExtension()`](http://php.net/splfileinfo.getextension) method?

Comment: @AmalMurali, Read somewhere that `exif` was a bit faster than that.

Comment: If anything, I guess `exif_*` would be slower as it requires additional checks. I'd just use `in_array($file->getExtension(), ['list', 'of', 'extensions']))` and be done with it :-)

Comment: @AmalMurali, Please feel free to edit the answer ^_^

Comment: Also, you probably meant this: `$images[$file->getFileName()] = $file->getBaseName();`.

Comment: I'm not *that* familiar with SPL extensions and [Iterators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12236744/1438393), so I *could* be wrong. I'll let someone else do that :)

Comment: This answer does not handle the prioritising by file extension, which was requested.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm not only working with images (which I maybe should have stated in the first place), and specifically through extensions (for a certain reason), the solution posted by Shankar won't really work for me.

So here is what I finally came up with:

```
$PriExts = array('png','jpg','jpeg','gif');

// ...

if (!in_array($Ext, $PriExts)) continue;
$i = array_search($Ext, $PriExts);
while($i > 0){
    if(file_exists($Dir.'/'.$Basename.'.'.$PriExts[--$i])){
        continue 2;
    }
}
```