# Using recursive function to delete files and directories, but how does it work?

Tags: php, recursion, recursiveiterator

I have some code I'm using I found on here, but would like to know how it actually works and what it's doing.

I gather it iterates through the various files and folders and removes them, but would like to know the mechanics so that I can make adjustments to target specific folders and it's contents.

```
function recursiveDeleteTD($dirPath, $deleteParent){

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dirPath, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST) as $path) {
    $path->isFile() ? unlink($path->getPathname()) : rmdir($path->getPathname());
}
if($deleteParent) rmdir($dirPath);

}
```

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreiciated :)

Thanks

Rob

Comment: You could try to iterate through the path, store all the paths you find and then filter out what you need. What is the problem you are trying to solve? You just need to delete files that match some kind of pattern?

Comment: You want that somebody explains you here the internal workflow of an php extention?

Comment: Just wondering how exactly the foreach loop is working.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12236744/4916265

Comment: Perfect :) Thanks for this :)

Comment: If that answers your question, please make sure that this posting gets properly retired.  Either write/accept an answer, or delete the question.