# Convert multidimensional array to file path

Tags: php, file, multidimensional-array

How do i convert multidimensional array to file path.
I have this array :

```
$data = [
        "users" => [
                "joe" => [
                        "photos" => ["a.jpg","b.jpg"],
                        "files" => ["a.doc","b.doc"]
                ],
                "annie" => [
                    "photos" => ["a.jpg","b.jpg"],
                    "files" => ["a.doc","b.doc"]
                ],
        ]
];
```

that i must convert to path example :

```
"users/joe/photos/a.jpg";
"users/joe/photos/b.jpg";
"users/joe/files/a.doc";
"users/joe/files/b.doc";

"users/annie/photos/a.jpg";
"users/annie/photos/b.jpg";
"users/annie/files/a.doc";
"users/annie/files/b.doc";
```

But i can't have the best result with this functions :

```
$path = "";
function iterate($data, $path)
{
  echo "<br>";
    foreach ($data as $key => $item){
        if (is_array($item)){
            $path .= $key.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            iterate($item, $path);
        }else{
            echo $path.$item."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

output :

```
users/joe/photos/a.jpg
users/joe/photos/b.jpg

users/joe/photos/files/a.doc
users/joe/photos/files/b.doc

users/joe/annie/photos/a.jpg
users/joe/annie/photos/b.jpg

users/joe/annie/photos/files/a.doc
users/joe/annie/photos/files/b.doc
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](https://www.php.net/class.recursiveiteratoriterator) + [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](https://www.php.net/class.recursivearrayiterator):

```
function computeFilePaths(array $fileTree): array
{
  $filePaths = [];

  $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($fileTree));
  foreach ($iterator as $fileName) {
    for ($folders = [], $pos = 0, $depth = $iterator->getDepth(); $pos < $depth; $pos++) {
      $folders[] = $iterator->getSubIterator($pos)->key();
    }
    $filePaths[] = implode('/', $folders) . '/' . $fileName;
  }

  return $filePaths;
}

print_r(computeFilePaths($yourArrayGoesHere));
```

I highly suggest [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077177/how-does-recursiveiteratoriterator-work-in-php/12236744)'s selected answer to understand how these iterators work.