# Search for txt files with a certain name and then delete them using PHP?

Tags: php, html, recursion, directory, unlink

Using the unlink function in php is it possible to search a directory with multiple folders for txt files with a certain name. In my case `Newsfeed.txt`

Where should I start with this ?

Comment: Get all file name inside a directory:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922954/getting-the-names-of-all-files-in-a-directory-with-php. now with foreach check the filename and delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great answer maxhb. Here's something a little more manual.

```
<?php

function unlink_newsfeed($checkThisPath) {
    $undesiredFileName = 'Newsfeed.txt';

    foreach(scandir($checkThisPath) as $path) {
        if (preg_match('/^(\.|\.\.)$/', $path)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (is_dir("$checkThisPath/$path")) {
            unlink_newsfeed("$checkThisPath/$path");
        } else if (preg_match( "/$undesiredFileName$/", $path)) {
            unlink("$checkThisPath/$path");
        }
    }
}

unlink_newsfeed(__DIR__);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the recursive directory iterators of the php standard library (SPL).

```
function deleteFileRecursive($path, $filename) {
  $dirIterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
  $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    $dirIterator,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
  );

  foreach ($iterator as $file) {
    if(basename($file) == $filename) unlink($file);
  }
}

deleteFileRecursive('/path/to/delete/from/', 'Newsfeed.txt');
```

This will allow you to delete all files with name `Newsfeed.txt` from the given folder and all subfolders.

Comment: Okay, I should have explained that php is very new to me. So The first part searches a set directory and puts all the results in $dirItnerator. I get that bit.

Comment: But I don't understand how to search the $dirIterator for files named Newsfeed.txt? and unlink all of them ?. Sorry

Comment: Edited example to meet your requirements.