# Unexpected output from reading my file

Tags: php

Everytime I use `echo readfile('./'); die;`  It just outputs 0, when I want it to read the files in the directory. I also tried

```
$files_open = readfile('./');
$original_file = explode("\n", $files_open);
print_r ($original_file);
die;
```

I get the same answer:

```
"0"
```

Is there another code or anything I could use to read my file? With my directory path being `'./'` ?

Comment: If you try to read file, than pass file name instead of directory path. `readfile` returns number of bytes read from file... So no file, means 0 bytes read. How to get files list in dir: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922954/getting-the-names-of-all-files-in-a-directory-with-php

Comment: You may want to try to use `file_get_contents`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: And have a look at [the manual page of the function you are using](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.readfile.php), you will soon realise that you are using it wrong or you are not using the right function...

Comment: I did file_get_contents  However my output was "Array =>0"  @Aerendir

Comment: Are you looking for `scandir`?

Comment: Yes, it outputs what you see as it is outputting the directory as told by Justinas. You have to pass a real file and not a folder. `./` is a folder while `./your-file.txt` is a file.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to read the content of every single file inside the directory as a concatenated string or return a string/array listing all the files inside your current directory so you can do some further processing?