# Here i want to retrive and display the images from db

Tags: php, sql, database

when i run the below code it shows output as encrypted symbols like this **[[�ѥ����1}j�i�Ƥ�^i�췼ܨ5���l�r�Ejק�r:��}=��""]�Q[n�C6���ZVv{����!���Y�j��>|�2��o��#\�T���hz`��d�vnW�KF���ih�ҍz�2����]**

i have more than 5 images in the database.

post your suggestions

```
    define('MYSQL_ASSOC',MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","phpapi");
    $query = "SELECT image FROM images";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
    $num =mysqli_num_rows($result);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {

    echo "<img src=\"$row[image]\" alt=\"img\" />";

                                    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Storing images in DB is not recommended. Instead, you should store image in filesystem and store file path in DB.

Comment: @AtaurRahman ok if store images in filesystem how can i retrive all images from same folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25988433/5527461

Comment: store the image files on disk, and store the _filenames_ in the DB, and use the DB records to generate your HTML image tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose `$row[image]` is the image content, but the image src attribute needs an url. You could

A) Convert the image content to a data url, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme (only suitable for small images), or

B) Specify an url that points to another php file that actually fetches the image from the database, i.e. something like

```
<img src="fetch-my-image.php?id=736">
```

and in fetch-my-image.php something like:

```
// ...
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id = /* id GET parameter here */");
// ...
echo $row[image]
```

Of course you should use prepared statement, which I haven't detailed here.
You should also set the correct MIME type in the HTTP response headers.

fetch-my-image.php should exactly echo the image contents to the output, nothing more.