# How to get files list from public folder Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have images in my `public` folder **(NOT STORAGE)** :

[image]

And I want to get all these files in a list and for each one, I do something ... 
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the names of all files in a directory with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922954/getting-the-names-of-all-files-in-a-directory-with-php)

Comment: Ahh! But I use laravel? can you put your answer if you want :)

Comment: You've got an answer from Mozammil

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could do this in one line:

```
use File;

$files = File::files(public_path());

// If you would like to retrieve a list of 
// all files within a given directory including all sub-directories    
$files = File::allFiles(public_path());
```

For more info, check the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#directories).

**Edit**: The documentation is confusing. It seems, you would need to use the `File` Facade instead. I will investigate a bit more, but it seems to be working now.

Also, the result will be an array of [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/de/class.splfileinfo.php) objects.

Comment: but I mean public in my script not Storage path :)

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: but how can I get, just name of my file?

Comment: You would do a foreach loop and then to get the filename, you can just do $file->getFilename();

Comment: Ok, I've used `getFileName()` - Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

**Solution 1 for Laravel**

```php
public function index()
{
    $path = public_path('test');
    $files = File::allFiles($path);

    dd($files);
}
```

**Solution 2 for Laravel**

```php
public function index()
{
    $path = public_path('test');
    $files = File::files($path);

    dd($files);
}
```

**Solution for PHP**

```php
public function index()
{
    $path = public_path('demo');
    $files = scandir($path);
    dd($files);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I've used this function and it's work :

```
// GET PUBLIC FOLDER FILES (NAME)
if ($handle = opendir(public_path('img'))) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo $entry."<br>"; // NAME OF THE FILE
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Thanks @MyLibary :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the **public** folder that is **not** in the **STORAGE** folder, but, if you want to **handle** this with Laravel Storage (Laravel Filesystem), You can define this folder as a Disk for filesystem and use it as follow.

In the filesystem config `config/filesystems.php`, `disks` part add this code:

```
'disks' => [

        ...

        'public_site' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(''),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        ...
    ],
```

And then you can use this commands in your app:

```
$contents = Storage::get('img/file.jpg');
```

or to get list of files:

```
$files = Storage::files('img');

$files = Storage::allFiles('img');
```

More details about Laravel Storage (Laravel Filesystem) is here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem

**Note** : If you changed Public folder you can use base_path() in the Disk definition with relative Path as follow (**Otherwise don't use it**):

```
'disks' => [

        ...

        'public_site' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => base_path('../../public'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        ...
    ],
```