# Get only files from a folder

Tags: php

I am using `PHP 7.4.1`.

I am trying to get files from a certain folder and I use the following code for this:

`array_diff(scandir($views . "/Text"), array('.', '..'));`

I have the following folder structure:

```
Texts/
├── test1.blade.php
└── Parts
```

`test1.blade.php` is a file and `Parts` is a folder.

The above code gives me back files AND folders.

I would only like to get all `.blade.php` files in my array.

Any suggestions how to filter out the folder(s)?

Appreciate your replies!

Comment: Iterate and check with `is_dir` for example.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774669/list-all-files-in-one-directory-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the names of all files in a directory with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922954/getting-the-names-of-all-files-in-a-directory-with-php)

Answer (score 3):

- `$result = array_filter($result, 'is_file');` - files
- `$result = array_filter($result, 'is_dir');` - folders

Comment: Thx for your reply! How can I use your `array_filter` function with my `array_diff(scandir($views . "/Text"), array('.', '..'));` when passing this as an array I get an error: `array_filter('is_file',array_diff(scandir($views . "/Text"), array('.', '..')));`

Comment: ups.. my fail, switch arguments: `array_filter($result, 'is_file')`

Comment: also u can use array_diff() but array_filter() remove root links in any case