# PHP list all files in directory

Tags: php, arrays, file, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the hierarchy of a directory with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660644/get-the-hierarchy-of-a-directory-with-php)
>   [Getting the names of all files in a directory with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922954/getting-the-names-of-all-files-in-a-directory-with-php)

I have seen functions to **list all file in a directory** but how can I list all the files in ***sub-directories too***, so it **returns an array** like?

```
$files = files("foldername");
```

So `$files` **is something similar to**

```
array("file.jpg", "blah.word", "name.fileext")
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.')) as $filename)
{
    // filter out "." and ".."
    if ($filename->isDir()) continue;

    echo "$filename\n";
}
```

PHP documentation:

- [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)
- [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)

Comment: +1 for SPL.  IMO its time (has been for a while) to start using SPL instead of these huge, slow procedural blocks.

Comment: Full code (change foldername) - `<?php`


`$path = realpath('yourfolder/examplefolder');`


`foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $filename)`


`{`


        `echo "$filename\n";`


`}`


`?>`

Comment: It includes `.` and `..` special dirs. Hopefully you can filter them out by adding a `!$filename->isDir()` test (there is no `isDot()`, see [SplFileInfo](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php)).

Comment: Also, useful links to PHP doc: [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) - [RecursiveIteratorIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php)

Answer (score 21):

So you're looking for a recursive directory listing?

```
function directoryToArray($directory, $recursive) {
    $array_items = array();
    if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if (is_dir($directory. "/" . $file)) {
                    if($recursive) {
                        $array_items = array_merge($array_items, directoryToArray($directory. "/" . $file, $recursive));
                    }
                    $file = $directory . "/" . $file;
                    $array_items[] = preg_replace("/\/\//si", "/", $file);
                } else {
                    $file = $directory . "/" . $file;
                    $array_items[] = preg_replace("/\/\//si", "/", $file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $array_items;
}
```

Comment: Do not use regexes in recursion, they tend to be very slow! In your case use rtrim function.

Comment: I rewrote this as a gist to be more efficient and only return files: https://gist.github.com/brucekirkpatrick/8528710

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for [php's glob function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php). You can call `glob(**)` to get a recursive file listing.

EDIT: I realized that my glob doesn't work reliably on all systems so I submit this much prettier version of the accepted answer.

```
function rglob($pattern='*', $flags = 0, $path='')
{
    $paths=glob($path.'*', GLOB_MARK|GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT);
    $files=glob($path.$pattern, $flags);
    foreach ($paths as $path) { $files=array_merge($files,rglob($pattern, $flags, $path)); }
    return $files;
}
```

from: http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=286156.0

Answer (score 2):

```
function files($path,&$files = array())
{
    $dir = opendir($path."/.");
    while($item = readdir($dir))
        if(is_file($sub = $path."/".$item))
            $files[] = $item;else
            if($item != "." and $item != "..")
                files($sub,$files); 
    return($files);
}
print_r(files($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to implement the reading of a given directory, and relying on the function of [Chuck Vose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203731/chuck-vose), I created this page to read the directories relying on JQuery:

```
<?php

/**
 * Recovers folder structure and files of a certain path
 * 
 * @param string $path Folder where files are located
 * @param string $pattern Filter by extension
 * @param string $flags Flags to be passed to the glob
 * @return array Folder structure
 */
function getFolderTree($path)
{
    //Recovers files and directories
    $paths = glob($path . "*", GLOB_MARK | GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT);
    $files = glob($path . "*");

    //Traverses the directories found
    foreach ($paths as $key => $path)
    {
        //Create directory if exists
        $directory = explode("\\", $path);
        unset($directory[count($directory) - 1]);
        $directories[end($directory)] = getFolderTree($path);

        //Verify if exists files
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            if (strpos(substr($file, 2), ".") !== false)
                $directories[] = substr($file, (strrpos($file, "\\") + 1));
        }
    }

    //Return the directories
    if (isset($directories))
    {
        return $directories;
    }
    //Returns the last level of folder
    else
    {
        $files2return = Array();
        foreach ($files as $key => $file)
            $files2return[] = substr($file, (strrpos($file, "\\") + 1));
        return $files2return;
    }
}

/**
 * Creates the HTML for the tree
 * 
 * @param array $directory Array containing the folder structure
 * @return string HTML
 */
function createTree($directory)
{
    $html = "<ul>";
    foreach($directory as $keyDirectory => $eachDirectory)
    {
        if(is_array($eachDirectory))
        {
            $html .= "<li class='closed'><span class='folder'>" . $keyDirectory . "</span>";
            $html .= createTree($eachDirectory);
            $html .=  "</li>";
        }
        else
        {
            $html .= "<li><span class='file'>" . $eachDirectory . "</span></li>";
        }
    }
    $html .= "</ul>";

    return $html;
}

//Create output
$directory = getFolderTree('..\videos');
$htmlTree = createTree($directory["videos"]);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
        <title>PHP Directories</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/jquery.treeview.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/screen.css" />

        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/lib/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/jquery.treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/demo.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <ul id="browser" class="filetree">
                <?php echo $htmlTree;?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The structure used in the tree with JQuery, the site was taken:
http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

I hope it is useful!