# Using RecursiveIteratorIterator to list files in folder is great. Can I get the parent path and full path as well?

Tags: php, file, spl

I need to list all files (which have certain extensions) in a folder and its sub-folders. I used RecursiveIteratorIterator as described in @Matthew 's great answer in [PHP list all files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826963/php-list-all-files-in-directory).

- I'm setting the root of the search to ".." and all filenames get a prefix of "../". How can I get the filename only?
- How can I get, in addition to the filename, its parent folder name?
- ...and how can I get the full path of the filename?

And one last thing: displaying a file-tree, or maybe all directories that have no sub-directories, are both examples of things that one might want to do when dealing with files. How would you recommend to pass this data to the client side and how would the data structure look like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`$filename` in that answer is actually not a string. It is an object of type [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) which can be used like a string but it also offers much more detailed info:

- [`SplFileInfo::getFilename()`](http://php.net/SplFileInfo.getFilename) -- filename.
- [`SplFileInfo::getPathname()`](http://php.net/SplFileInfo.getPathname) -- path to the file
- [`SplFileInfo::getPathInfo()`](http://php.net/SplFileInfo.getPathInfo) -- SplFileInfo object for the path
- [`SplFileInfo::getRealPath()`](http://php.net/SplFileInfo.getRealPath) -- canonicalized absolute pathname; see [`realpath()`](http://php.net/realpath) for more info and the difference to *Pathname*,

Comment: Thanks, works great. But what about the parent directory? @sectus

Comment: @user1639431, $file_info->getPathInfo() should return SplFileInfo object of parent directory.

Answer (score 3):

Using this as a base:

```
$iter = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('../');

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iter) as $fileName => $fileInfo) {
   $fullPath = (string) $fileInfo;
}
```

Each `$fileInfo` will return a [`SplFileInfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php) object. The path and filename are easily accessible in addition to a host of other methods.

```
phpSplFileInfo Object
(
  [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => ./t.php
  [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => t.php
)
```

I may be mistaken, but to access the parent folder name unless you record it through the tree the simplest would be using `dirname` and appending `../` to the path.

Comment: Martin, what kind of exception are you trying to catch? Documentation said nothing about exceptions in `__toString()`.

Comment: Oops, I pasted it from an open file I had which utilises functions which do throw exceptions, forgot to remove it.. Fixed!

Comment: @Martin: Cast to string instead of using `->__toString()`. This is what is intended by that function *and* it does not leak any exceptions. (You may have done that for debug reasons, but for code here, take the straight variant).

Comment: Also I think you wanted to outline that that the object also offers a path relative to the base-path of the recursive directory iterator. You might want to make this more visible / show a little demonstration. Just commenting.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $iterator = new FilesystemIterator(dirname(__FILE__), FilesystemIterator::CURRENT_AS_PATHNAME);
    foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
        echo $iterator->current()->getPathname() . "\n";
    }
 ?>
```