# PHP Directory and Files Recursive Listing

Tags: php, recursion, directory-listing

I tried to edit this PHP code to specify a directory for recursive listing of files and sub directories but no joy.

any ideas is greatly appreciated.

I just found this code from this link:

[PHP list all files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826963/php-list-all-files-in-directory/10228005#10228005)

And here's the code below:

```
    <?php

    /**
    * Recovers folder structure and files of a certain path
    * 
    * @param string $path Folder where files are located
    * @param string $pattern Filter by extension
    * @param string $flags Flags to be passed to the glob
    * @return array Folder structure
    */


    function getFolderTree($path)
    {
    //Recovers files and directories
    //$paths = glob($path  . "*", GLOB_MARK | GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT);
//@param string ($path ".\temp" );
//$path = ".";

    $paths = glob($path . "*",  GLOB_MARK | GLOB_ONLYDIR | GLOB_NOSORT);
    $files = glob($path . "*");


    //Traverses the directories found
    foreach ($paths as $key => $path)
    {
    //Create directory if exists
    //$directory = explode("//", $path);
    $directory = explode("\\", $path);
    unset($directory[count($directory) - 1]);
    $directories[end($directory)] = getFolderTree($path);

    //Verify if exists files
    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        if (strpos(substr($file, 2), ".") !== false)
            $directories[] = substr($file, (strrpos($file, "\\") + 1));
    }
    }

    //Return the directories
    if (isset($directories))
    {
    return $directories;
    }
    //Returns the last level of folder
    else
    {
    $files2return = Array();
    foreach ($files as $key => $file)
        $files2return[] = substr($file, (strrpos($file, "\\") + 1));
    return $files2return;
    }
    }

    /**
    * Creates the HTML for the tree
    * 
    * @param array $directory Array containing the folder structure
    * @return string HTML
    */
    function createTree($directory)
    {
    $html = "<ul>";
    foreach($directory as $keyDirectory => $eachDirectory)
    {
    if(is_array($eachDirectory))
    {
        $html .= "<li class='closed'><span class='folder'>" . $keyDirectory .  "</span>";
        $html .= createTree($eachDirectory);
        $html .=  "</li>";
    }
    else
    {
        $html .= "<li><span class='file'>" . $eachDirectory . "</span></li>";
    }
    }
    $html .= "</ul>";

    return $html;
    }

    //Create output

    $pathx = 'temp/';
    //$directory = getFolderTree($pathx);
    $directory = getFolderTree($pathx );

    $htmlTree = createTree($directory[$pathx]);
    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>PHP Directories</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/jquery.treeview.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/screen.css" />

    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/lib/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/lib/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/jquery.treeview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/demo.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
        <ul id="browser" class="filetree">
            <?php echo $htmlTree;?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What does it do that you didn't expect? What, if any, error messages did you get? Where is the error exactly? Did you investigate? How about printing some debugging information in your `createTree` method? Help us to help you.

Comment: It's working now, I just did what Marcin has suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

The first is the directory separator - you should use the constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of `\`, e.g.:

```
$directory = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path);
```

This will make your code valid not only on windows but also on unix systems.

The second problem is here:

```
$htmlTree = createTree($directory[$pathx]);
```

There is no key `$pathx` in the `$directory` array. Probably it should look like this:

```
$htmlTree = createTree($directory);
```

But please note that it's hard to tell what results you expect and what errors did you get.

Comment: Thank you Marcin, for your help and understanding. Yes, it works great. Just getting my hands wet on PHP, hope to grasp it. So I will be able to help others as well. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Find out how to debug your code. Use functions like `var_dump` to dump values of variables (even complex arrays) so you will be able to see what is going on. The code above works now but try to investigate how `getFolderTree` works inside, what are values of variables on each step etc. If you knew how to do that before you would be able to find a different solution by yourself or post detailed description what exactly does not work as expected.