# Display all files and filesizes in directory

Tags: php

This script is working perfectly :

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

BUT it's not return any sub-directory files...
This return all sub-directories files but not the current directory...

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*/*") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

How do I get all files include directories and directories in single request ?

Comment: `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`

Comment: @JayBlanchard ...and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3826963/ ;-) but I'll let somebody else close 'er up.

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.