# scan directory for files and folders & show it in treeview in angular

Tags: php, angularjs, treeview

Does anybody know, how I can scan the files on server (in PHP) for files and folders to list them in a downable treeview using angular?

Comment: Where is your effort ? Show us some code :p

Comment: It's only a question to get a tip :) the effort will come after I get some usable tipps.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to scan the directory with this sample : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827000/4682796

Then you change the array structure with a key => value pair for each element.
You output the new array with json encode and then you use this
http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular.treeview to make it work