# Display Files names from Folder in PHP

Tags: php, html, file, directory

I have a tree of files like this

- --Folder1
- ----File1.1
- ----File1.2
- ----File1.3
- --Folder2
- ----File2.1
- ----File2.2
- ----File2.3 . .

I want to display all folders in combobox, if a chose a folder ; the lists of files of this folder can display in other combobox in HTML/PHP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP list all files in directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826963/php-list-all-files-in-directory)

Answer (score 1):

```
$dir = 'some directory';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if (is_dir($entry) && $entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo "$entry\n";
        }
    }
}

closedir($handle);
```