# Listing only folders and subfolders in PHP, putting them in menu

Tags: php, subdirectory

I want to make a site where I can upload new folders at will, and then have them automatically added to my menu.

I have a file system looking like this:

procedures 
-procedure 1 
  -folder 1 
 
  -folder 2
-procedure 2 
-procedure 3
  -folder 1
  -folder 2
  -folder 3

The problem is that I need it to look like this
[ul id="menu1"]
[li]procedure 1[/li]
[ul class="menu2"]
[li]folder 1[/li]
[li]folder 2[/li]
[/ul]
[li]procedure 2[/li]
[li]procedure 3[/li]
[ul class="menu2"]
[li]folder 1[/li]
[li]folder 2[/li]
[li]folder 3[/li]
[/ul]
[/ul]

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the hierarchy of a directory with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/660644/get-the-hierarchy-of-a-directory-with-php). You only need to apply the [id_dir()](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-dir.php) function to each result to pick only dirs and subdirs.

Comment: @amenadiel `is_dir()` not `id_dir()`