# Code for displaying Index items on web?

Tags: html, web-services, default-value

Ok so I've made an basic upload system with php to upload files from a device to a selected folder.

Trouble is the look of the folder where the files go to is basically the default index look(Basically it looks bland)

I'm wondering what code (html, php etc.) can display the items inside as a more user friendly way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Get the hierarchy of a directory with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660644/get-the-hierarchy-of-a-directory-with-php)

... and style that using css or use a javascript api like [Galleria](http://galleria.io/) or [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/demo/)