# Array of all files in folder and subfolder with out path

Tags: php, arrays, scandir

I have some folder structure like this

```
/photos/1/file1.txt
/photos/2/file2/txt
```

What i need is to get inside folder **photos** and get array of all files without path, final array should look like this

```
$content = ('file1.txt', 'file2.txt');
```

This is what i have for now, but still not like with final array

```
function recursive_scandir($dir){
    $contents = array();
    foreach(scandir($dir) as $file){
        if($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
        $path = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;
        if(is_dir($path)){
            $contents = array_merge($contents, recursive_scandir($path));
        } else {
            $contents[] = $path;
        }
    }
    return $contents;
}

print_r(recursive_scandir('photos/'));
```

Comment: What are you getting as a result? What is wrong with the result?

Answer (score 1):

You should search better:
[Get the hierarchy of a directory with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/660644/get-the-hierarchy-of-a-directory-with-php)

After you get your file with path like "/photos/1/file1.txt", you can use [basename](http://php.net/basename).